# Black stains in wood, identifying the cause

Tags: wood, mold

I found a used bedroom furniture set which includes a bed frame and box spring. I've put together the bed frame but upon looking at the box springs more closely, I see there are some dark stains around the edges.

[image: black stains]

How can I determine whether this is mold or a wood destroying organism, or something else?

I also noticed that looks similar to signs of dry rot, but I'm not sure.

[image: Dry rot?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears like mold, I found a link that goes over some simple ways to test if something is mold.

https://www.familyhandyman.com/list/how-to-test-for-mold/

I personally would check if the wood is soft, if the wood has an earthy smell... like the smell of dirt and decomposing leaves, both strongly indicate mold.